# How to push a number in an Array in angular4?

Tags: arrays, angular

I am trying to push a number in an array when i click on a button but it does not seem to work.

In my app.component.html:-

```
<div>
    <label>Number of days:- 
        <input [(ngModel)]="numDay"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" (click)="onClickMe()">OK</button>
    </label>
</div>
<p>{{dayNum}}</p>
```

In my app.component.ts :-

```
  private numDay : number;
  private master1 : number;
  private dayNum = [2,3];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dayNum.push(8);  
  }
  onClickMe() {
    this.master1 = (this.numRace*1);
    this.dayNum.push(99); // <<<<--- This does not seem to work
  };
```

You can check my code in Plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/jM3NDu7V3AjzOWeuCoDi?p=preview

Thank you for your help

Comment: I suspect angular checks `dayNum` as an array object and since you mutate this object angular can't recognize any changes. So you will also always see old value. Changing to `{{ dayNum + ''}}` may change something :)

Comment: To see what @yurzui is talking about, take a look at [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/n0GRuyqXowkDaJWfH4nf).

Comment: Try using an ng-repeat on the output array instead of {{dayNum}}

Comment: Hi Vega,It works with cosole.log(this.dayNum) and you are right that I will add input value to that array.

Comment: all you guys are right

Comment: {{dayNum |json}}

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before and it turned out to be to do with change detection in Angular.

My solution was to do a shallow copy instead of a push. But a *ngFor may solve this also.

```
this.dayNum = [...this.dayNum, 9];
```